# I want to make a projector show an image displayed on surfaces

Tags: effects

I would like to make a scene where a movie projector displays an image onto a wall but the image will get projected onto obstacles or even characters that pass between the projection wall and the projector. I have no clue how to accomplish this effect in Blender or even someway to do it in post.

I don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: Try UV project modifier.

Comment: Connect a texture to a point light's color attribute.

Answer (score 3):

In your scene, add a lamp as the type **spot**.

With the lamp object selected go into the texture panel, under the lamp texture, add a texture with your image. You probably want to set *Extension* to *Extend*. Set the coordinates to object and input the lamp as the mapping object.

[image]

You can also set the spotlights shape to a square by ticking *Sqare* in the lamps settings.

[image]

Even overlapping *projector* lamps work.

[image: image projection from spotlight]

Comment: That is just beautiful.

Comment: I am trying to pull of something similar in Cycles. This in BI works nice, however the image does not scale with distance of the light, which is a bummer. Didn't find a solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

To scale the image according to distance you can use Drivers applied to the Scale values of the Mapping node.

[image]

To add a Driver to a value just Right-Click on its field and select Add Driver option, or press Ctrl+D.

[image]

In the Driver Property panel :

1. use a Transfrom Channel type ( the one with the icon : (x) ) as the Driver variable,
2. set a reference object (mine is named Plane),
3. set the type to one of the axes (here I set it to Z Location as the lamp is facing down on the Z axis),
4. fine tune the effect in the Expression field. Here you are mapping the Z Location values to Scale values, so they need to be scaled down (*0.2, moving the object 1 meter along Z axis will change the Scale by 0.2) and maybe inverted (*-1) with particular positioning

[image]

Here are my results (bottom plane is the reference, watch the other two move and behave naturally) :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice how I can set the full image scale by moving the bottom plane (which was the Plane object reference in the Driver property panel), so it is similar to a real life situation when you are adjusting/setting the projector zoom to a background wall.

[image]
[image]