# How do you simulate an LCD projector where a lamp projects a patterned light onto a surface? (cycles)(cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, light

I found an answer for Blender Internal engine at [I want to make a projector show an image displayed on surfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/i-want-to-make-a-projector-show-an-image-displayed-on-surfaces)

But I want to accomplish something similar in Cycles.  I tried attaching a texture node to the lamp's node tree, but it seems the color pattern is based on the world coordinates and does not rotate with the spot lamp.

[image: node setup for textured spot lamp]

What is the correct node setup for a cycles lamp so that its texture rotates and moves with the lamp?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that my real problem was that my 2.78a version of blender was haunted, because switching to 2.78c solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a spotlight using the pretty much the same node setup as you have but with an additional mapping node to position the image.

[image]

You also need to be sure to set the spotlight light size to something small or your projected image will look blurry.

[image]

And the result.

[image]

Update:

Here's it working with your blend file, no settings changed:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might have to go into a little more detail.  I added that mapping node, but when I rotate my lamp, the texture does not move with the spot light, so it is no improvement over my original node setup.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem...  The mapping node just fixes to orientation of the image.  The image rotates with the spotlight for me.  Could you upload a .blend?

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47047 in case you want to see an example of a .blend with my problem.  If I alter the rotation of the lamp, the texture doesn't move with the spot.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?  The texture rotates fine for me with your blend file.

Comment: I am using blender 2.78a

Comment: There must be something different between our environments because your blend file, on my machine with 2.78a is doing exactly what you want it to do.