# shape acquisition from structured light

Tags: lighting

I am working on 3D reconstruction using structured light technique. Can the hardware(consisting of camera,a projector) be simulated in blender to generate the light pattern and project it on the object so that the generated images can be used to plot the point cloud?

Comment: You can use a lamp to project a texture, or use the UV project modifier to project the texutre over UV unwrapped objects. Related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62665/avoid-distortions-when-creating-projector-effect and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64147/i-want-to-make-a-projector-show-an-image-displayed-on-surfaces/64162#64162

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90698/projecting-onto-a-mirror-and-back