# How to find correspondence between an image and its projection onto an object?

Tags: python, scripting

Complete newbie here. I have set up a projector (following [these insructions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/145942/79235)) where a point light projects an image pattern onto another object (ie. cube or sphere or whatever). Now I need a script that can find correspondences between (u, v) coordinates of the 2D image that is being projected and the (x, y, z) coordinates of the object onto which the image is being projected. How can I accomplish this?